# Alterar background de uma tabela

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Preciso de uma ajuda, eu tenho uma pagina web com duas tabelas, uma tabela tem 5 `divs` com imagens dentro dela, imagens já pré-definidas, ao clicar sobre alguma dessas imagens mude o background da outra tabela. Como posso fazer isso usando PHP, HTML e JS.

Alguém tem um tutorial, código experimental, qualquer coisa que possa me ajudar a realizar essa operação, agradeço desde já.

CÓDIGO:

```
<td height="351" valign="top" align="center">
   <div class="fundo"> </div>
   <div class="fundo"> </div>
   <div class="fundo"> </div>
   <div class="fundo"> </div>
   <div class="fundo"> </div> 
</td>
```

CSS:

```
.fundo {
   font-size: 1em; 
   text-align: center; 
   line-height: 40px; 
   height: 52px; 
   width: 52px; 
   margin: 4px; 
   margin-left:32px; 
   border: 2px solid black; 
   float: left; 
   padding: 2px;
 }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Podes colocar o código HTML que tens?

Comment: Jessica: clica em [edit] e coloca isso na pergunta, de preferência a(s) `<table>` completa(s)

Comment: É só uma tabela com 5 divs igual a imagem, com uma classe com o estilo das divs, e uma tabela vazia, só para receber a cor.

Answer (score 4):

Fiz aqui um exemplo simples para você modificar e usar para resolver seu problema.

Explicação :

> As cores de cada div estão setadas no 'BACKGROUND' no seu caso como
>   vai ser imagem provavelmente vai usar 'background-image', independente
>   de como for fazer precisa modificar no evento do click qual atributo
>   você quer pegar da div que recebeu o click para passar para div geral,
>   ou tabela , ou qualquer elemento. Observe que adicionei o evento click
>   em [cor] um atributo que setei em todas as divs que vão ter essa ação.

```js
$(function(){
  $('[cor]').click(function(){
    var bg = $(this).css('background');
    $('.cor-escolhida').css('background',bg);
  });
});
```

```css
.div{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  float:left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.azul{
  background: blue;
}
.amarelo{
  background: yellow;
}
.vermelho{
  background: red;
}
.preto{
  background: black;
}
.verde{
  background: green;
}
.cor-escolhida{
  background: #ededed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  float:left;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div cor="true" class="div azul"></div>
<div cor="true" class="div amarelo"></div>
<div cor="true" class="div vermelho"></div>
<div cor="true" class="div preto"></div>
<div cor="true" class="div verde"></div>
<div class="cor-escolhida"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se entendi direito, mas acho que você está montando o layout de seus site através de tabelas? *Se for isso mesmo aconselho a não continuar dessa forma, usamos o conceito de que tabelas são para fazer tabelas :) que tal?*

Criei aqui 10 `divs` 5 com background coloridos e 5 com background de imagens.
Estou utilizando o Jquery que troca o `background` da `div class='resultado'` pelo mesmo `background` da `div` que foi clicada.` Perceba que apenas 1 linha de código já resolve a troca.

```js
$('.pad').on('click', function(){

  $('.resultado').css('background', $(this).css('background'));
  
});
```

```css
.pad{

  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}


.resultado{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='pad' style='background-color: red'>

</div>
<div class='pad' style='background-color: pink'>

</div>
<div class='pad' style='background-color: orange'>

</div>
<div class='pad' style='background-color: blue'>

</div>
<div class='pad' style='background-color: gray'>

</div>
<br>
<div class='pad' style='background: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSjDTixrnTBJkS5W8sVP8nUbqAI0Q0A1EivmZ6ebjBoxqliLVnc")'>

</div>

<div class='pad' style='background: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTiFIvETpnGCxMpLfIClByX3CoNj1CLUXZECUNkDX6ktHpqhSq1")'>

</div>

<div class='pad' style='background: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcScprXKYMyyAiep-_dpYdu6lcVNMn6v_IFoQJCCIfeZf-sJMjrIXQ")'>

</div>

<div class='pad' style='background: url("http://www.meapaixonei.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/conheca-10-curiosidades-sobre-o-sorriso.jpg")'>

</div>

<div class='pad' style='background: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ6gBy5fsABIPzfEOZpVYBrMICap1JdADWxDGjPMF40Gn6j4ZEJ")'>

</div>

<div class='resultado'>

</div>
```

**Observações**

- O estilo apresentado não está dentro de tabela ou coisa do tipo, mas repare que ao aplicar a lógica, onde quer que for este método deverá funcionar.
- As imagens se repetem na `div class='resultado'`, caso a imagem seja pequena demais. Isso é espaço para uma outra pergunta. Mas deixo aqui de ante mão um link para que você possa lidar com esse problema caso seja necessário.

[Sobre background](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) 
[Perfect Full Page Background Image](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) *(A famosa mão na roda)*

Answer (score 1):

Ola, fiz um exemplo básico usando jquery.

https://jsfiddle.net/telizpablo/5rfn0kbp/3/

no atributo **`data-color`** você define a cor que aquela div transformará a **`table2`** (pode ser HEX também ) ;)

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#suaTabela td div.fundo').click(function () {
            $('#tabelaAlvo').css('background', $(this).css('background'));
            //ou
            salvaBanco();
            //ou            
            window.location.href = 'www.meusite.com/index.php?cor=' + $(this).css('background');
        });
    });
</script>
<table id="suaTabela">
    <tr>
        <td height="351" valign="top" align="center">
            <div class="fundo"></div>
            <div class="fundo"></div>
            <div class="fundo"></div>
            <div class="fundo"></div>
            <div class="fundo"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Na função "salvaBanco();" você deve utilizar AJAX (https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) para gravar no banco sem precisar recarregar a página;

Caso não possa utilizar AJAX, terá que submeter algum formulário usando método POST e pegando o valor via PHP $_POST["cor"].

Caso também não consiga utilizar o método POST, podes usar o JavaScript para redirecionar a página para ela mesma utilizando parâmetro (QueryString) e usando $_GET["cor"] para salvar no banco;

```
/*código PHP localizado na parte superior da index.php citado no exemplo */
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["cor"])){
        GravaNoBanco($_GET["cor"]);
    }
?>
```